# Email verification from JMeter failed when build from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I am using JMeter to test an API. There is a feature where an email notification is sent. Using the following script to verify email notification in my local machine works fine. But when I use JENKINS then the test failed. The rest of the scripts passed from JENKINS but failed only in this email notification request.

```
REQUEST DATA: 
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.search.RecipientStringTerm
import javax.mail. *
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore

props.setProperty('mail.transport.protocol', 'imaps')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.host', 'imap.gmail.com')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.port', '995')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.ssl.enable', 'true');

def session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
store = session.getStore('imaps')
store.connect('imap.gmail.com', '####@gmail.com', '####')
inbox = store.getFolder('Inbox')
inbox.open(javax.mail.Folder.READ_ONLY)


def onlyToGivenUser = inbox.search(new 
RecipientStringTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO,'###@gmail.com')); 

try {
    onlyToGivenUser.each { message ->
        ByteArrayOutputStream emailRaw = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(emailRaw);
        SampleResult.setResponseData(emailRaw.toString(), 'UTF-8');
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Something went wrong", ex);
        OUT.println("Something went wrong", ex);
        throw ex;
    }

RESPONSE HEADERS: 

RESPONSE MESSAGE: 
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in 
via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)

RESPONSE DATA:
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article:

> "Please log in via your web browser and then try again" should be pretty self-explanatory.

> Alternative option could be [turning on "Access for less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

[image]

> If above steps don't help here is a [full checklist](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229)

Comment: Hi, @dimtri I am not having an issue with JMeter. Using Jmeter, I can read the email, but when I integrate that Jmeter script in Jenkins and trigger build from there, then it cannot read an email. I have done all the necessary changes in Gmail.